# NodeJS Returning Data

Tags: node.js, undefined

I have the following code which isn't returning data properly.

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    var au = authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err,data) {
            if(err) {
                    return 'error';
            }
            console.log(data);
            return data;
    });     
    if(au) {
            sess.username = au.name;        
    }
    res.end('done');
});
```

Data is passed all the way to console.log(data); but when I try to use in in the au statement, its returning undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic async problem. `authme` is running asynchronously so the code isn't running simply from top to bottom.

```
var au = authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err,data) {
  console.log('I am second!')
});     

console.log('I am first!')
```

You need to restructure the code a bit to get the desired behavior.

```
app.post('/login',function (req,res) {
  authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return 'error';
    }

    if (data) {
      req.session.username = data.name;
    }

    res.end('done');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the functional call to `authme` is asynchronous. Put your `if` statement in the callback of the function call, to assure it is always validated after the asynchronous function has completed execution.

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    (authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err,data) {
            if(err) {
                    return 'error';
            }
            console.log(data);

            if(data) {
                    sess.username = au.name;        
            }
    }))();
    res.end('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Nodejs operations are asynchronous - in short it means that result is resolved later, you don't know exactly when, while code execution goes on, not waiting for it. The way to handle such call are the callbacks. More on that topic [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-the-asynchronous-nature-of-nodejs--net-36183).

So with your code you fall into that classical trap. This part of the code

```
   var au = authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err,data) {
            if(err) {
                    return 'error';
            }
            console.log(data);
            return data;
    });
```

is an asynchronous call, that means that this part

```
 function(err,data) {
                if(err) {
                        return 'error';
                }
                console.log(data);
                return data;
        }
```

is a **callback** that runs only when result is obtained. While this part

```
if(au) {
            sess.username = au.name;        
    }
```

is executed *immediately* after `var au = authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass)` is done.
By that moment there is no `au` resolved so that is why you're getting this error.

In your case you should put au check into the callback:

```
authme(req.body.name,req.body.pass, function(err,data) {
            if(err) {
                    return 'error';
            }
            if(au) {
              req.session.username = au.name;        
        }
            res.end('done');
    });
```